# Error when installing package "plotly" in R

Tags: r, macos, package, installation, plotly

When I tried to install the package "plotly", it returned the following error message:

```
* installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
** package ‘data.table’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c assign.c -o assign.o
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [assign.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/data.table’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘data.table’ is not available for package ‘plotly’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/plotly’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘plotly’ had non-zero exit status
```

After some quick search this seems to be due to an incompatibility with MacOS High Sierra? I was able to install other packages like 'ggplot2' though. I'm very new to R and would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The `non-zero exit status` simply indicates that there was an error during the installation of the "package".

File link : https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/plotly_4.8.0.tar.gz

Try with the following command:

```
install.packages('FILE_PATH', repos=NULL, type = "source",dependencies = TRUE)
```

Doing so, all the dependencies for the package will also be downloaded. Downloading from source will recompile the package and installs.